# Connection timed out for RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest

When I am trying to call a Post Restful using `RestTemplate`, I getting time out error, however I am able to get response from postman.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
MultiValueMap<String, String> map2 = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map2, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,String.class);
```

Below is error trace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1227) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1175) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingAsyncClientHttpRequest$1.call(SimpleBufferingAsyncClientHttpRequest.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingAsyncClientHttpRequest$1.call(SimpleBufferingAsyncClientHttpRequest.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
```